# How to obtain a readable spline formula in R?

Tags: r

In the code below I store and use in `f` a function obtained from a `splinefun` function. I can use it, however I would like to print the function in a readable format to understand the calculation.

```
x <- 1:7
y <- c(2,4,3,2,1,1,2)
f <- splinefun(x, y, method = "natural")
f(1)
f(2)
f(3.5)
```

If I print the function

```
print(f)
```

I always get the following, no matter the input attributes

```
function (x, deriv = 0L)  
{
    deriv <- as.integer(deriv)
    if (deriv < 0L || deriv > 3L) 
        stop("'deriv' must be between 0 and 3")
    if (deriv > 0L) {
        z0 <- double(z$n)
        z[c("y", "b", "c")] <- switch(deriv, list(y = z$b, b = 2 * 
            z$c, c = 3 * z$d), list(y = 2 * z$c, b = 6 * z$d, 
            c = z0), list(y = 6 * z$d, b = z0, c = z0))
        z[["d"]] <- z0
    }
    res <- .splinefun(x, z)
    if (deriv > 0 && z$method == 2 && any(ind <- x <= z$x[1L])) 
        res[ind] <- ifelse(deriv == 1, z$y[1L], 0)
    res
}
<bytecode: 0x00000000089957a0>
<environment: 0x0000000007b8a700>
```

How can I get the formula in a format such as f(x) = a + bx + cx^2 ... ?

Comment: R is not meant as a tool for symbolic algebra. It's focus is on numerical approximation so the explicit coefficients are not stored. Plus cubic splines have a bunch of places where the formula changes. You're not actually fitting a simple polynomial. If you wanted to do that you should do some form of regression. Then you could extract the coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The points for evaluation and the coefficients of the polynomial approximations are stored in the environment of the function. These would be passed to `C_SplineEval, x, z)`:

```
 ls(envir=environment(f))
#[1] "z"
 environment(f)$z
#-----------------------
$method
[1] 2

$n
[1] 7

$x
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

$y
[1] 2 4 3 2 1 1 2

$b
[1]  2.8076923  0.3846154 -1.3461538 -1.0000000 -0.6538462  0.6153846  1.1923077

$c
[1]  0.0000000 -2.4230769  0.6923077 -0.3461538  0.6923077  0.5769231  0.0000000

$d
[1] -0.80769231  1.03846154 -0.34615385  0.34615385 -0.03846154 -0.19230769
[7]  0.00000000
```

Response to comment/question about note in help page: Looking at the NEWS file one sees this entry:

`approxfun()` and `splinefun()` now return a wrapper to an internal function in the stats namespace rather than a `.C()` or `.Call()` call. This is more likely to work if the function is saved and used in a different session."

Comment: Is it possible to save the function between sessions? Help says "safer after 3.0" not sure what that means